# Create a list of strings from a string having '+' character. Using '+' to separate the lists

Tags: python, string, if-statement, string-formatting

I have a sample input string as follows:

```
med_str = 'Film-coated tablet + ALpha Chloro, Prolonged-release tablet + ALFU Dioxide'
```

I want to create a list of strings separated by '+'. OUTPUT expected:

```
med_str = ['Film-coated tablet', 'ALpha Chloro'], ['Prolonged-release tablet', 'ALFU Dioxide']
```

There might be cases where there would be only one '+' separated string. Example:

```
new_str = 'Tablet + DEFLAZo'
```

OUTPUT expected:

```
new_str = ['Tablet', 'DEFLAZo']
```

How do I do this using an if else in python which should take care of all the cases and create a separate list of strings separated by comma whenever there is/isn't one or more than one elements with '+' in the string and separated by comma.

Comment: Looks like split on `', '` followed by splitting each of the results by `' + '`

Comment: Have you tried to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your string always has a whole number of paris, here's how it could be done:

```
med_str = 'Film-coated tablet + ALpha Chloro, Prolonged-release tablet + ALFU Dioxide'

cleaned = [s.strip() for s in med_str.replace('+',',').split(',')]
result = [[cleaned[i], cleaned[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(cleaned), 2)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['Film-coated tablet', 'ALpha Chloro'], ['Prolonged-release tablet', 'ALFU Dioxide']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
med_str = [i.split(" + ") for i in med_str.split(", ")] # Gives output as list of lists.
```

or

```
med_str = tuple(i.split(" + ") for i in med_str.split(", ")) # Gives output as tuple of lists.
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting a nested list which I am not looking for. How to only keep each list separated by comma and not a list of lists

Comment: @7answers, your expected output `med_str = ['Film-coated tablet', 'ALpha Chloro'], ['Prolonged-release tablet', 'ALFU Dioxide']` is actually a tuple of list. You can get the desired result either as a list of lists or tuple of lists. Otherwise, the final result would get flattened like `['Film-coated tablet', 'ALpha Chloro', 'Prolonged-release tablet', 'ALFU Dioxide']`.

Comment: Yeah then how do I make it into a tuple of lists from list of lists

Comment: What is the reason that we cannot get output as this: ['Film-coated tablet', 'ALpha Chloro'], ['Prolonged-release tablet', 'ALFU Dioxide']

Comment: Please note : `z = list1, list2, list3` is same as `z = (list1, list2, list3)` in python3. You can verify this using python3 shell. For example, declare one variable `a  = 1,2,3` and another one `b = (1,2,3)` and check `a == b` which would return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Use First Splinting the (,) if its success it will split list into different list with two string concatenated now just split with (+) to get The Remaining Result

```
med_str = 'Film-coated tablet + ALpha Chloro, Prolonged-release tablet + ALFU Dioxide'

final=[l.split("+") for l in med_str.split(",")]
print(final)
```